# Resetting inner form control in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form control loanTerm which has another 2 inner form control years and  months, I'm trying to reset it via

```
this.form.control['years'].reset();
```

Unfortunately it is not working because when I access the properties of this.form.control the only available object is the loanTerm.

```
<df-years-months-question ng-reflect-_model="[object Object]" ng-reflect-minimum-period="48" ng-reflect-maximum-period="474" ng-reflect-question-label="Loan term" ng-reflect-name="loanTerm" id="loanTerm" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid"><div class="form-inline ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]">
  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
  <div class="input-group col-xs-5 col-sm-3">
    <input class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" formcontrolname="years" type="number" ng-reflect-name="years" min="48" max="474">
    <span class="input-group-addon">years</span>

  <div class="input-group col-xs-5 col-sm-3">
    <input class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" formcontrolname="months" max="11" min="0" type="number" ng-reflect-name="months">
    <span class="input-group-addon">months</span>
  </div>
</div>
</df-years-months-question>  
  </div>
```

I've tried the following: unfortunately none works

- `this.form.control['loanTerm'].reset();`
- `this.form.get('loanTerm').get('years').reset();`

Comment: Can you post your html and not the compiled one?

Comment: You have a **formgroup** `loanTerm`, not **form control** right? It's a bit unclear what you want to achieve. What hould be reset? Also could you show the actual code, both TS and template :)

Answer (score 0):

You can only reset the full form not a single input box instead try
 in your ts

```
    export class HeroDetailComponent4 {
  form: FormGroup;


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.form= this.fb.group({
     "years":"",
     "months":""
    });
  }
}
```

and in your html

```
 <form [formGroup]="form" novalidate>
     <div >

              <div >
                <input formControlName="years" type="number" >
                <span class="input-group-addon">years</span>

              <div class="input-group col-xs-5 col-sm-3">
                <input formControlName="months" ">
                <span class="input-group-addon">months</span>
              </div>
            </div>
    </form>
      {{ form.get('years').value }}
```

now you can null the model value in ts

Comment: thanks for the reply. But unfortunately it is not working because when I check the properties inside the this.form.control there is no years there.

Comment: ok now I noticed you don't have a form tag I am editing the answer